# Graphics glitches in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm having graphics issues with Visual Studio 2010. When I open a solution only part of the UI renders. Entire sections like the solution explorer will be missing.

This only happens after I've had Visual Studio running for a while and have opened/closed a variety of solutions.

It "feels" like some sort of a GDI handle leak because the problem goes away once I reboot.

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate - 64 bit. I've updated my graphics drivers, installed the latest patches, etc. I can't find any postings about this on stackoverflow or doing a variety of Google searches.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you actually have to reboot or can you just restart VS?

Answer (score 7):

It's a known issue, seems like no fix is coming in SP1, see https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/575376/visual-studio-2010-code-editor-problems?wa=wsignin1.0 & the workaround described at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2023207 (disabling HW-Acceleration & Visual Experience adjustment did the trick for me).

Try also to update the graphic driver to their latest version.

Comment: It wasn't Visual Studio but another software based on Visual Studio libraries, it fixed my problem, I'm so glad.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio 2010 UI has been rewritten from the ground up in WPF.  Myself and a couple of other devs in our team are experiencing the same issues (various hardware and software but my software is the same as yours).  In our case closing and reopening VS solves it with no reboot required.

It's a cracking product but roll on SP1.

Answer (score 0):

Running Visual Studio under Administrator (Run as Administrator) fixes the problem for me.